# Birefringent filters: Showing that phase shift is inversely proportional to wavelength from my data

Tags: optics, birefringence

[image]

[image: Plot of Phase shift against wavelength]

I started out by taking two sets of data for the crossed and parallel setup without the birefringent filter. The crossed setup being when destructive interference occurs and the parallel being 90degrees rotation of the analyser from the crossed setup(max transmission). The birefringent filter was then placed and the spectrum of Intensity(counts) against wavelength recorded for both crossed and parallel setups. Given these equations

$$\Delta \Phi=2\pi \Delta l/\lambda=2\pi d\Delta n/\lambda$$ for $\Delta n = n_e-n_O$ where we assume the difference in refractive index for the extraordinary and ordinary directions is constant and

$$i_{crossed}=sin^2(\frac{\Delta \Phi}{2})$$
$$i_{parallel}=cos^2(\frac{\Delta \Phi}{2})$$
we can rearrange for
$$\Delta \Phi=2arctan\Big(\sqrt{\frac{i_{crossed}}{i_{parallel}}}\Big)$$
This final equation is my plot. Noting that $i_{crossed}=\frac{I_{crossed}}{I_{crossed}+I_{parallel}},i_{parallel}=\frac{I_{parallel}}{I_{crossed}+I_{parallel}}$ are normalised so the output of the sin and cos equations is between [0,1]. Where $I_{crossed}$ and $I_{parallel}$ are the measured intensity data from the spectrometer.

My issue is now using this to show that the phaseshift is inversely proportional to the wavelength. Some pointers are here https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.1834920?class=pdf. But they know the number of layers in their filter. Is it possible without? I get it must be something to do with the peaks getting further apart?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want to show is that the slope on the rising side of the plot "hills" is linear and is the same for every hill.  Same for the down slopes.  It appears that the amount of measurement error is greater at the peaks and troughs, so you can mostly ignore what's going on there.

Comment: Could I get an indication as to why this slope would show the required relationship?

Comment: I may have misunderstood part of your question.  The vertical axis refers to phase difference, not phase shift.  How are you defining the phase difference, and how did you measure the phase difference?

Comment: Sorry, I should be referring to phaseshift throughout, I have corrected this.

Comment: It's not clear yet how you measured the phase shift.

Comment: I recorded the intensity vs wavelength for the crossed and parallel setups described above using the spectrometer. If the ordinary or extraordinary directinon of
the filter happens to be aligned with the polarisation direction of the light after
the polariser, you should see peaks and troughs as I did.The arctan equation was then used to plot the above graph. Noting that the icrossed, iparallel is normalised.